# Google Sheets - use script across multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I can't get this script to work across the other tabs/sheets within my worksheet. It works on the current sheet, but I need to duplicate that across the other sheets within my worksheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  var date = new Date();
  var t = date.getTime();
  var r = e.range.getA1Notation();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(t,r);
}

function unCheck() {
  var d = new Date();
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var day = 1000; //milliseconds for 1 full day 86400000
  var keys = props.getKeys();
  for(var i in keys){
 Script    var t = parseInt(keys[i]);
    if(d.getTime() - t > day) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(props.getProperty(keys[i])).setValue("FALSE");
      props.deleteProperty(keys[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `onEdit` works on current sheet. Any edit, it saves into Properties service, but which sheet the A1 range belongs to, is not saved. So, without that info, `unCheck` cannot just blindly edit other sheets except current sheet. You need change in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != 'TRUE') return;
  var date = new Date();
  var t = date.getTime();
  var r = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var n = e.range.getSheet().getName(); // get sheet name
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(t, r + '__|__' + n); // include sheet name
}

function unCheck() {
  var d = new Date();
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var day = 1000; //milliseconds for 1 full day 86400000
  var keys = props.getKeys();
  for (var i in keys) {
    var t = parseInt(keys[i]);
    if (d.getTime() - t > day) {
      var values = props
        .getProperty(keys[i])
        .toString()
        .split('__|__'); // split to get range and sheet name
      var a1 = values[0];
      var n = values[1];
      SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(n)
        .getRange(a1)
        .setValue('FALSE');
      props.deleteProperty(keys[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far.  I am a complete novice so bear with me.  I have tried running this but am still having some trouble.  Does the sheet name in the onEdit function include the apostrophes just like you have included above?  In other words 'sheet 1' just like that?  It feels like I am creating syntax errors, which is why I am asking the follow up questions.

Comment: Quotes are used to denote string values. **__|__** is a value so we put it inside quotes like this `'__|__'`.  Just like **TRUE** and **FALSE** in code.  `getName()` function gets sheet name as is.  If we need to literally pass that value into something we'll use quotes around it. Variables do not require quotes aroung them. I did not use sheet names literally anywhere. Do you have quotes in your sheet names?